# resize forms based on controls visibility

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on .net win forms application. I have three controls which are placed in a form. These controls are visible based on a condition. When these controls are made invisible I am seeing a blank space on the bottom of the form. I wanted to eliminate the blank space when the control is not visible and the form size should automatically resize when the control is visible. What options/settings/code should I be using?

Comment: Please post what you have tried (the code).

Comment: As as aside, off-topic comment, you wouldn't be struggling with these kind of issues if you were using current (< 10 years, XAML-based) technology.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of someone who's using panels from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/14daa166-68a2-429f-8b6d-678648319e4a)

```
private void panel3_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
if (panel3.Visible == false)  
{  
if (panel3.Tag == null)  
panel3.Tag = panel3.Height;  
panel2.Height += (int)panel3.Tag;  
}  
else 
{  
if (panel3.Tag == null)  
panel3.Tag = panel3.Height;  
panel2.Height -= (int)panel3.Tag;  
}  
}
```

If you're using just a form you could use the Form.size property

```
form1.Size = New Size(150, 200)
```